# How to retrieve string from resource file in codebehind?

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a Resource Dectionary in main project.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<system:String x:Key="ToolbarNewButton" >Add</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="localizedMessage" >Delete Item</system:String>
```

and a class library that add it to main project. I use DynamicResource in it.

```
 <Label Content="{DynamicResource ToolbarNewButton}"  Foreground="{DynamicResource InputFontColor}"/>
```

I want to retrieve string from resource file in codebehind. I use this code but get **ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException**

```
string localizedMessage = (string)Application.Current.Resources["localizedMessage"];
```

Comment: Did you include the resource dictionary in `App.xaml`?

Comment: Yes,it find, when i use dynamicresource in Xaml, but  don't find when use in code behind

Comment: I just tried this and can access the string value without any problem from the `MainWindow` constructor... where are you trying to access it from?

Comment: @sthotakura : Thanks a lot, I added resource dictionary in mainwindow. I add resource in `App.xaml` :)

Answer (score 0):

I know, this post is couple of months old, but thought I will put my comment as an answer, so that it helps someone else.

The OP didn't include the resource dictionary in App.xaml. It worked once he added the resource dictionary in `App.xaml`.

Comment: I don't think this solution works if you need to use more than one Resource Dictionary.

Comment: You could always include all resource dictionaries in App.xaml. or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess it works for OP's case, but it's not working for me using more than one dictionary.

Comment: Post your XAML, lets have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's the first one 
Here's the code:

ResourceDictionary rd = System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0];

object theValue = rd["localizedMessage"];

string theString = (string)theValue;