# How to control DynamicResource implementation in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, dynamicresource

In my program I would like to implement a `DynamicResource` from code-behind. Right now I am binding the `Content` of a `Label` to a `string` property in my Data Model...

```
<Label Content="{Binding DataModel.StringValue}" ... />
```

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247324/how-to-retrieve-string-from-resource-file-in-codebehind), I have implemented the `string` in my Data Model like so:

```
private string _stringValue = (string)Application.Current.Resources["nameOfResource"];
public string StringValue
{
    get { return _cartsInSystem; }
    set
    {
        _cartsInSystem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => CartsInSystem);
    }
}
```

I would like to make it so that every time the user changes the Resource Dictionary, this `string` value updates with the new value.

I am trying to achieve the same effect as something like this:

```
<Label Content="{DynamicResource nameOfResource}" ... />
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, and how I might correctly implement something like this.

**UPDATE 1:** As requested by @HighCore, this is an example of my code where I only have access to `string` values from code-Behind (or C# class)

(This is part of a ViewModel of a `TreeView` in my MainWindow)

```
//The "DisplayNames" for these nodes are created here and not accessible through xaml.
//This is because the xaml window has access to this code through it's itemsSource
private HierarchicalVM CreateCartsNode()
{   
    return new HierarchicalVM()
    {
        DisplayName = "Carts",
        Children = 
        { 
            new CartConnection() { ConnectionDataModel = new CartConnectionModel(), DisplayName = "Cart Connection" }, 
            new HierarchicalVM() {
                DisplayName = "Cart Types",
                Children = {
                    CreateCartType( new CartConfigModel() { DisplayName = "Default" }, new CartIO_Model() ),
                },
                Commands = { new Command(OpenAddCart) {DisplayName = "Add..."} }
            }
        }
    };
 }
```

This is the xaml of the above `TreeView`:

```
<!-- Tree view items & Functions -->
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DataTree.Data}" ... />
```

**Update 2:** I have another perfect example of my problem...

I have a `comboBox` that has it's `itemsSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection` in my Data Model. Like so:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _objCollection;
private string _notUsed = "Not Used";
private string _stop = "Stop";
private string _slow = "Slow";

public DataModel()
{
    ObjCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>() { _notUsed, _stop, _slow };
}

public ObservableCollection<string> ObjCollection {...}
```

xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataModel.ObjCollection}" ... />
```

If I want to make it so that the items in this `comboBox` change when the resource dictionary is changed, it looks like I'll need to handle it in C# rather than xaml.

Comment: Could you not simply use `{DynamicResource nameOfResource}` as you mentioned in the question? if so, why?

Comment: I can't use that because a lot of my content in this program is created in Code-Behind

Comment: You should not be creating or manipulating UI elements in code behind. You're only creating problems by doing so.

Comment: Some of the `strings` in my program that need to be displayed are created and only accessible from code behind.

Comment: Can you show an example of that?

Comment: Sure, I've made an update to the question

Comment: `The "DisplayNames" for these nodes are created here and not accessible through xaml` - Wrong. You can bind to that: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeNode.DisplayName}"/>`

Comment: Would I have to alter the binding of my Tree then?

Comment: I have no idea dude. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why is that always such a mystery... haha? I'm trying to implement a language change. I'll need to make it so that those nodes are set as a `DynamicResource` so that they change whenever the `ResourceDictionary` does.

Comment: @Ericafterdark if you bind your `TextBlock.Text` to `SomeNode.DisplayName`, then whenever you change `DisplayName`, it will update the Text, is that what you trying to achieve?

Comment: @sthotakura Yes, but since my `TreeView` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` through it's `itemsSource`, where does `TextBlock.Text` come in?

Comment: @Ericafterdark I just picked `TextBlock.Text` as an example, in your case it is `Label.Content`.

Comment: Okay, but what I'm saying is, all of the nodes are already displayed in the window with the `TreeView` coded in xaml like it is above. Do I need to restructure it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After OP's **UPDATE 2** and having a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41562?noredirect=1) with him for a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247324/how-to-retrieve-string-from-resource-file-in-codebehind), I understood he was trying achieve localisation for his application. He would change Resource Dictionaries (for different languages) on the fly, and he wanted his C# code re-read/load values from `Application.Current.Resources`.

**APPROACH ONE**

After you changing the Resource Dictionary, You could use something like `EventAggregator`/`Mediator` to let other parts of the application (including ViewModels) know about Resource Dictionary change, and they respond to it by re-loading/reading resources/values from `Application.Current.Resources`

**APPROACH TWO**

OP doesn't want to introduce any new dependencies like `EventAggregator`/`Mediator`. So, I suggested this second approach. I know, it is not pretty, but here it goes..

You could have a **global static** event instead of EventAggregator/Mediaotr to let other parts of the application know that you swapped resource dictionary, and they will re-load/read values.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7045758/587690) answer about potential problems with static events and their subscriptions.